# How do I pull from a data list for parameter values in a system of ODEs and then solve and plot?

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, differential-equations

I have a parameter set list and I would like to solve a system of ODEs multiple times using each parameter set in the list.  Then I would like each set of solutions to be graphed on the same plot.

For example:

I have imported this list of parameter sets:

```
{{ "a", "b", "c", "d"}, {1, 5, 1, 3}, {2, 3, 2, 2}, {3, 3, 3, 1}}
```

Then I have this system

```
system={x'[t] == a*x[t] + b*y[t], y'[t] == c*x[t] + d*y[t], x[0] == 10, y[0] == 0};
```

I would like to substitute each parameter set in for a,b,c,d respectively, then solve using

```
sol = DSolve[system, {x[t], y[t]}, {t}]
```

for each parameter set (or NDSolve, ParametricNDSolve if appropriate)

Then I would like all sets of solutions to be plotted on the same graph

```
Plot[{x[t] /. sol, y[t] /. sol}, {t, 0, 7}, PlotRange -> Automatic].
```

Note, I would like to use this example to understand the process and apply it to a larger system with more parameters and a larger list of sets of parameters.

Answer (score 1):

This is the procedure.  Just ask if you have questions regarding details.

```
params = {{1, 5, 1, 3}, {2, 3, 2, 2}, {3, 3, 3, 1}}

sol = ParametricNDSolve[system, {x, y}, {t, 0, 10}, {a, b, c, d}]

Table[
 Plot[{(x @@ p)[t], (y @@ p)[t]} /. sol // Evaluate, {t, 0, 10}],
 {p, params}
]
```

For more examples check here: [`ParametricNDSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ParametricNDSolve.html).

Comment: Is there a way to plot multiple solutions on the same graph as opposed to each parameter set generating a whole new plot?

Comment: @Megan Yes, but that leads to other questions, for example, how do you differentiate the datasets?  How do you separately differentiate `x` from `y`?  It would lead to code which mostly deals with plot styling, so I suggest you ask a separate and specific question about that.  If you apply `Show[..., PlotRange->All]` to the table, it will combine them to a single plot but won't give a useful result for the reason I state it.